# High val_acc, but low accuracy in practice

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been following the code from [this website](https://www.kaggle.com/estebancortero/applying-kaggle-s-deep-learning-tutorial) to train a CNN that can distinguish between 10 monkey species. During the training phase I get decent results with 3 epochs:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 1097 images belonging to 10 classes.
Found 272 images belonging to 10 classes.
Epoch 1/3
46/46 [==============================] - 24s 521ms/step - loss: 1.4526 - acc: 0.5644 - val_loss: 0.5665 - val_acc: 0.9688
Epoch 2/3
46/46 [==============================] - 20s 445ms/step - loss: 0.5706 - acc: 0.8983 - val_loss: 0.4078 - val_acc: 0.9375
Epoch 3/3
46/46 [==============================] - 21s 449ms/step - loss: 0.3696 - acc: 0.9447 - val_loss: 0.4832 - val_acc: 0.8438
```

Then I wrote a prediction script that looks at a directory and makes a prediction from the saved model. I tried pointing it at both the training and validation folders, but both of the results seem correct about 16% of the time. Why does my `val_acc` seem high during training but when I actually use the model to make a prediction, it performs poorly?

Here is the prediction loop:

```python
inputSize = (300, 400, 3)
for count, path in enumerate(allImages):
    img= cv2.imread(path)

    img = cv2.resize(img, (inputSize[0], inputSize[1]))
    img = np.reshape(img, (1, inputSize[0], inputSize[1], inputSize[2]))

    correct = path.split(os.path.sep)[-2] #get label from directory
    classes = labels[model.predict(img)[0].argmax(axis=0)]

    if args.show_predictions: #display prediction in a window
        fontSize = 0.8
        black = (0, 0, 0)
        white = (255, 255, 255)

        orig = cv2.resize(orig, (480, 480))
        cv2.putText(orig, 'prediction: {}'.format(classes), (0, 20),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontSize, black, 10)
        cv2.putText(orig, 'prediction: {}'.format(classes), (0, 20),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontSize, white, 2)

        cv2.putText(orig, 'answer: {}'.format(correct), (0, orig.shape[0] - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontSize, black, 10)
        cv2.putText(orig, 'answer: {}'.format(correct), (0, orig.shape[0] - 10),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontSize, white, 2)
        cv2.imshow('prediction', orig)
        if cv2.waitKey(0) == ord('q'):
            break

    if args.verbose:
        print('prediction: {} --> answer: {}'.format(classes, correct))

    if classes == correct:
        totalCorrect += 1

    counter += 1
    if count%verbosity == 0:
        print('Predicting image {} out of {}'.format(count, len(allImages)))

print('total correct: {}/{} - {}%'.format(totalCorrect, counter, int(totalCorrect/counter * 100)))
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Basically it reads the label from the directory and compares it to a `label` list I made earlier in the script.

Upon running the script with the **training** data (which I thought would be high since it was trained on it), I get:

```
Predicting image 600 out of 1097
Predicting image 650 out of 1097
Predicting image 700 out of 1097
Predicting image 750 out of 1097
Predicting image 800 out of 1097
Predicting image 850 out of 1097
Predicting image 900 out of 1097
Predicting image 950 out of 1097
Predicting image 1000 out of 1097
Predicting image 1050 out of 1097
total correct: 161/1097 - 14%
```

What makes the accuracy high during training, but low in practice?

EDIT: Running the script in verbose mode:

```
Predicting image 0 out of 272
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: bald_uakari --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: bald_uakari --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: bald_uakari --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: bald_uakari
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
Predicting image 50 out of 272
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: black_headed_night_monkey
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: pygmy_marmoset --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: common_squirrel_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: pygmy_marmoset --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: pygmy_marmoset --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
Predicting image 100 out of 272
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: japanese_macaque
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: mantled_howler
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: nilgiri_langur
Predicting image 150 out of 272
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: nilgiri_langur
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: pygmy_marmoset --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: patas_monkey
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
Predicting image 200 out of 272
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: pygmy_marmoset --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: pygmy_marmoset
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: nilgiri_langur --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: patas_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: silvery_marmoset
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
Predicting image 250 out of 272
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: japanese_macaque --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: pygmy_marmoset --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: white_headed_capuchin --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
prediction: common_squirrel_monkey --> answer: white_headed_capuchin
total correct: 41/272 - 15%
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could run your code in the verbose mode and show the output of this line: `print('prediction: {} --> answer: {}'.format(classes, correct))`

Comment: @KiraMichiru, Just added the verbose output to the question. looks like it's just straight up wrong most of the time.

Weird how the `val_acc` and `acc` were both high, but I get poor accuracy on both these sets when I try and measure it :c

Comment: The output shows that you actually get different predictions, however, the predictions are far from random. You nearly always get common_squirrel_monkey as prediction, which is strange. Next, try to output `model.predict(img)` directly and see whether also there you can see the same pattern of one class being highly overpredicted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as it turns out, I was using the wrong channel input mode. The pre-trained network I was using is called `resnet50` from the keras library, and it uses the `caffe`c style input.

The solution is to import `preprocess_image()` from keras, then run

`img = preprocess_image(img)`

Another factor was me loading images with `cv2.imread`. I'm uncertain but this may use the wrong channel format that resnet50 requires. The alternative is to use keras' `load_img()` function.

**Conclusion: val_acc is generally correct during training. If your prediction accuracy is poor it is likely a data input problem!**